# Присвоение значения из файла переменной при инициализации. (C#)

Tags: c#

Задача при запуске программы получать числовое значение из файла (обычный текстовый файл содержащий двузначное число) и присваивать переменной типа int trialStart. Так же цикл должен каждую итерацию считывать значение из файла и сохранять его, потом брать новое значение и т.д. Когда я объявляю эту переменную, то она как бы 0 по умолчанию (а мне нужно что бы было значение из файла). То есть при вхождении в цикл у этой переменной значение 0 и в файле значение меняется на ноль. Что я делаю не так?

```
while (j < i)
{
    j++;
    using (StreamReader trial = new StreamReader(@"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\browser\trial.smd"))
    {
        string v = trial.ReadLine();
        int trialStart = Convert.ToInt32(v);
    }

    using (StreamWriter tw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\browser\trial.smd"))
    {
        tw.Write(trialStart++);
        tw.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: `tw.Write(trialStart++);` что это должно сделать? Может, `tw.Write(++trialStart);`?

Comment: что такое `i`? что такое `j`? Зачем они в вашем коде и для чего вам `d`?

Comment: извините( d это опечатка была.... d там вообще не нужно. Исправила.

Comment: i и j управляющие переменные цикла, суть не в них.
Извините( d это опечатка была.... d там вообще не нужно. Исправила.
Вопрос в том как заставить trialStart брать значение из файла при вхождении в цикл. Он 0 изначально, так как в начале программы инициализирован и при вхождении в цикл он записывает в файл 0, а потом прибавляет по одному. А мне надо что бы он прибавлял по одному к значению из файла, а не менял его на ноль.

Comment: Вам написали ответ ниже, он вам не помог?

Answer (score 1):

Внимательно читайте предупреждения компилятора.

Вы объявили новую локальную переменную `trialStart` внутри блока `using (StreamReader trial...`.

```
using (StreamReader trial = new StreamReader(@"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\browser\trial.smd"))
{
    string v = trial.ReadLine();
    /*int*/ trialStart = Convert.ToInt32(v);
    int d = Convert.ToInt32(v);
}

...

    tw.Write(++trialStart);
```